# How to update a Gravity Forms $entry $field_id after 3rd party response?

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

When my GravityForm is submitted it successfully posts the submitted entry data as a JSON array to a (3rd party) API. The API creates an object, assigns a random id to it and then returns the id along with the rest of the array, in the request response.

How can I retrieve the random id from the request response and save it to a hidden field in the previously submitted GravityForm entry?

This is what the 3rd party API response looks like:

```
{
        "url": "http://domain.com",
        "name": "companyName",
        "random_id": 4224
}
```

Comment: response.random_id

Comment: @KrisRoofe - thanks for your comment but how can I implement response.random_id with GFAPI::update_entry_field( $entry_id, $input_id, $value ); from here https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/api-functions/#update_entry_field ?